# Angular - How to add an access token from an observable to an outgoing HTTP request?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, angular-httpclient

in my `UserService` I've got a user `Observable` object which holds the `UserModel` of the user logged in. For testing I've implemented inside the `ngOnInit()` the login process:

```
this.userService.authenticate('###', '###')
   .subscribe(res => console.log('authenticated'));
```

```
private userSource = new BehaviorSubject<UserModel>(null);
   public user = this.userSource.asObservable();
```

My UserModel provides an attribtue called authKey which is used for the API auth.

In my `ProjectService` I would like to do an api request; in order to do this, the api key stored in the `UserModel` is necessary. It would possible just to subscribe the user attribute, but I read about avoiding to do subscriptions inside services.

**Question**

How can I connect this subscriptions with pipes/mapping? My approach was the following code; but that feels like bad code.

```
suggest(term: string): Observable<ProjectModel[]> {
      return this.userSrv.user.pipe(
         mergeMap((user: UserModel) => {
            const options = {params: {'access-token': user.accessToken}};

            return this.http.get<ProjectModel[]>(this.conf.url, options).pipe(
               map(response => {
                  // mapping the projects ...
                  return projects;
               })
            );
         })
      );
   }
```

Comment: Do you add this access token to every outgoing request from your client app?

Comment: Yes, excepting the login process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the previous answer, a [HTTP Interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) is best suited for your use case.

The  basic idea would look like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {mergeMap,map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

function isLoginRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>): boolean {
    // implement
}

@Injectable()
export class AccessTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService){}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if(isLoginRequest(req)) return next.handle(req);
    return this.userService.user.pipe(
      map(user => req.clone({setParams:{'access-token': user.accessToken}})),
      mergeMap(req => next.handle(req))
    );
  }
}
```

**Dont forget** to register this interceptor as exemplified in the docs.

By using this, your original service function is reduced to:

```
suggest(term: string): Observable<ProjectModel[]> {
  return this.http.get<ProjectModel[]>(this.conf.url).pipe(
           map(response => {
              // mapping the projects ...
           })
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing every request the access token, you should use an HttpInterceptor : https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor .
It will add the AccessToken every http request you do.
Store the user in a BehaviorSubject in your UserService and use it inside the Interceptor.

After this, your function will look like this :

```
suggest(term: string): Observable<ProjectModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<ProjectModel[]>(this.conf.url + '/my-endpoint');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm already using the BehaviorSubject (see edit) - but what's the best practise to access the BehaviorSubject in the HttpInterceptor? Assuming another situation where it's "necessary" to make nested subscriptions; best practise?

Comment: The intercept function asks for an Observable so you can use your BehaviorSubject in the pipe to get the access token (or something else) without subscribing.